# Java ArrayList same string grouping and get most frequent String

Tags: java, string, list, java-stream

i have a List with Strings and group the same Strings.

```
List<String> allTypes = new ArrayList<String>();

Map<String, Long> count = allTypes.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

and then i get the count of the most frequent String

```
Long max = Collections.max(count.values());
```

Now i dont want only the count of the most frequent String i want the
associated String too. The List is randomly filled with Strings from a other List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking to:

```
Optional<Map.Entry<String, Long>> maxEntryByValue = count.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Or if you want it without `Optional`, you can use:

```
Map.Entry<String, Long> maxEntryByValue = count.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
        .orElse(null); // or any default value, or you can use orElseThrow(..)
```

Comment: The `max` call can be written more succinctly as `max(Map.Entry::comparingByValue)`.

Comment: You should probably mention that in case that 2 Strings (keys) have the same count, only one entry will be returned. In case the requirement would be to return multiple map entries if the maximum isn't a unique value i guess you could do that with something like `List<Entry<String, Long>> maxEntries = count.entrySet().stream().filter(x -> x.getValue().equals(Collections.max(count.values()))).collect(Collectors.toList());` (Probably not very effective, just my first idea)

Comment: @VGR I tried your solution in side but it *Cannot resolve method 'comparingByValue'*

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS yes, I agree, if the OP wait a multiple value, then he/she should follow another approach.

Comment: @YCF_L [It should be there.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue())

Comment: what I have to do if i just want the string for example "stackStr" not like "stackStr=201"

Comment: @Swipi do you mean `maxEntryByValue.getKey()` ?

Comment: Yes thank you !!! Thank You for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the entries and if the *value* matches your *targetValue* then store that key in the `Set<K> keys`. This will contain all the keys having that particular *targetValue*

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      String key = entry.getKey();
      Object value = entry.getValue();
      if (value.equals(targetValue)) {
        keys.add(entry.getKey());//add the keys to the set<K> keys
      }
    }
    return keys; //all the keys having the same targetValue will be in this set
```